# map inside map ( Map as key)

Tags: c++

I have created map inside following way.
Ex: map first;
and I have to created second map into following way as per my requirement.

map second. 
So first is the key value for  in second map.

I have inserted data into both map. 
first.insert("Test1",1);
second.insert(first,2).

First Just I wantt to know is it correct way to do implementation. or Should I use another stl.?

I am facing one issue with this code (Not compliation issue). If I get data from database in following way than the value does not insert into second map.

first.insert("Test1",2);
second.insert(first,1). But I belive that it should enter into map as ("Test1"  && 1) and
("Test" && 2) both are diffirent key for second map.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes FWIW: a map as key would _not_ be mutable. `std::map<>::value_type` is `std::pair<const key_type, value_type>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to use a map as a key type?
Keys should be small, since you have no guarantee how many copies of them will STL do. Using (potentially large) std::map as a key will kill your apllication's performance.

Comment: std::, not std::, first. map itself has constant size, it can be used as key.

Comment: But copying a map involves copying all of its elements, right?

Comment: Well, it can be implementation-dependent - some map implementation can be COWs. Secondly (again, I don't know implementation details), it can be passed as `const`, in which case it wouldn't be copied... And uh, I meant you should change every occurrence of "STL" in your post with "stdlib"; check my answer.

Comment: Worse than copying the key is the fact that the *comparison* is abysmally slow on containers. Comparison is the thing that's done a *lot* by every map operation.

Comment: I am and always was using "STL" as "Standard Template Library".

Comment: The purpose of this implemenation was to store value into map from database and avoid to hit database. Example. select name from emp where empid ='23' and place like 'india';  so we need to store value empid + place = Name ( you can assume it will return unique key). change the variable name because of company issue

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, right, you are using it - but it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for "STL", let me quote !stl from ##c++ at freenode:

> `STL' is sometimes used to mean: (1) C++ standard library; (2) the library Stepanov designed at HP; (3) the parts of [1] based on [2]; (4) specific vendor implementations of either [1], [2], or [3]; (5) the underlying principles of [2]. As such, the term is highly ambiguous, and must be used with extreme caution. If you meant [1] and insist on abbreviating, "stdlib" is a far better choice.

Next: of course you can use map as key, but there is probably no comparator for it (I doubt there is std::less for map...). But remember - comparator doesn't check if parameters are equal - it checks, whether first is less than/greater than the second, because it's easier to model every possible relations using "less than":

```
a == b <=> !(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

And now, **more ontopic**:

From what you have written, I don't quite get the point of having map<map, anything else>. Could you provide some testcase? I will be able to give you complete answer, then.

Comment: A comparator is defined for most standard containers, lexicographic in terms of the element comparator (i.e. using `std::equal_range` or something like that).

Comment: The purpose of this implemenation was to store value into map from database and avoid to hit database. Example. select name from emp where empid ='23' and place like 'india'; so we need to store value empid + place = Name ( you can assume it will return unique key). change the variable name because of company issue